# Solving nonlinear system of differential equations in wolfram mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, system, differential-equations, nonlinear-functions

How can I solve nonlinear system of differential equations and get plot for this solution? The system is without initial conditions. For example,

x'= (x + y)^2 - 1
y'= -y^2 - x + 1

Comment: type `DSolve` and press `F1`

Answer (score 0):

[Introduction to Differential Equation Solving with DSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveIntroduction.html)

See also [Setting Up the Problem](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveSettingUpTheProblem.html)  scroll down to In(5) to see
how to set up a system of differential equations.